# Timeout for grant select on sys.gv_$instance

Tags: oracle

When executing the following grant as SYS user:

```
grant select on sys.gv_$instance to <username>;
```

I sometimes get a timeout:

```
SQL Error: ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object
```

I have a test DB where it worked and 1 where I get the timeout (or sometimes works after some minutes). Both are Oracle 12.
Is there a reason for this timeout/lock?
As a workaround I created a view and granted the view to the user which always worked.

Comment: What I have heard is that it is better to avoid touching the **_$** tables and instead work with the normal ones. So for instance, can you try to give the required access to gv$instance and check if it helps fixing the issue? Thanks

Comment: When I try to grant select on sys.gv$instance, I am getting a "ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views". SYS.GV$INSTANCE is a public synonym which points to the view GV_$INSTANCE. This view selects from GV$INSTANCE, which is not the public synonym again but some internal stuff (I think).

Comment: thanks I guess it is something I am not aware of...best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Reboot the Oracle 12c database, then execute the grant statement.
   or
2. Find out what session / process is blocking the grant and kill it:

```sql
select inst_id, username, BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS, BLOCKING_INSTANCE,
 BLOCKING_SESSION, SID, SERIAL#
from gv$session
where username is not null;
```

Get the SID and session # of the account preventing the grant (in my case it was DBSNMP), log into the correct database instance as SYS and kill it:

alter system kill session ',<serial#>' immediate;

(replacing the text  and <serial#> with the correct numbers, example:
alter system kill session '438,48555' immediate;)